# English reference of an article

Tags: reference-request, entropy

I wonder if anyone has a copy of the famous article "*Entropie geometrique des feuilletages*" in English. I unfortunately don't understand French very well, and I would like to know if there is an English version of it.

The article can be found at this [link](https://perso.ens-lyon.fr/ghys/articles/entropiegeometrique.pdf), from the Ghys personal page.

Comment: As French is my language, I can translate for you at least the first pages in the case nobody can indicate a translation, say in the coming 12 hours.

Comment: I don't remember it very well, but I thought someone had commented to me that there was an English version....

Comment: So, wait and see ? I you have to contact me, please prefix your comment by my pseudo in order to be sure that it reaches me.